# Magento 2.2 Module not loading

Tags: magento2.2

I've created a M2 (2.2.7) module but:

1. code is not visible under /generated folder
2. log stmts not written
3. template file not being called

All suggests that there is something wrong with the way of deployed the code?

The namespace is Fws & the module is called SideMenu. So I have a block at the following location

> `app\code\Fws\SideMenu\Block\SideMenu.php`
>
> module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Fws_SideMenu" setup_version="0.0.2" schema_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Fws\SideMenu\Block\SideMenu">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="deleteorderAction" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="context" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context</item>
            <item name="helper" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category</item>
            <item name="flatstate" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State</item>
           <item name="menu" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

> registration.php

```
     <?php  
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Fws_SideMenu',
        __DIR__ 
    );
```

My frontend layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar-main">
            <block class="Fws\SideMenu\Block\SideMenu" name="sidemenu" template="Fws_SideMenu::sidemenu.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Finally, my block is as follows:

```
<?php
// get current store's categories
$categories = $block->getStoreCategories();
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<div class="block-title block-navpro-title" id="fws-sidebar">
    <h2>Our Products</h2>
</div>
<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
 <ul id="menu" data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":false,"delay":300, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left+10 top+30"}}}'>
<?php
    foreach($categories as $category):
         if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            continue;
         }
    ?>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
        <?php
        if($childrenCategories = $this->getChildCategories($category)):
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach($childrenCategories as $childrenCategory):
             if (!$childrenCategory->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
             }
        ?>
        <li class="ui-menu-item"><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($childrenCategory) ?>"><?php echo $childrenCategory->getName() ?></a></li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
    endif;
    endforeach;
    ?>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I've deployed like so:

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento module:enable Fws_SideMenu
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:flush
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I'm running in developer mode so static-content: deploy is not really required but ....

Anyone any ideas why the code is not being compiled (I've run `php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile` a couple of times)

and why my template file is not outputting?

Thanks,
Eddie

Comment: is there any error when you tried to compile it with setup:di:compile?

Comment: please update your block file

Comment: Edwin - I think the code is being compiled - it's not showing any errors. But what I can't understand is why this code is not being called. I think I'll try to rewrite my module as a widget - at least then I should be able to see if the code is being called!